# How to find sum of salary all of employees under each manager with out including manager salary in the sum?

Tags: sql, database, join

How to find sum of salary all of employees under each manager with out including manager salary in the sum?

Format of employees table:

[image: 1]

Comment: Sandrine's manager is Frank, who is an analyst, not a manager. Frank's manager is Jonas, whose job is actually "manager". So, two questions: (1) Do you need to include Sandrine's salary in the total reported for Jonas (even though she only reports to him indirectly, not directly)? (2) Do you need to compute a total for Frank, who is not a "manager" but who is, in fact, Sandrine's manager?

Comment: Also: MySQL and Oracle are different products (even if, by accident, owned by the same corporation). Please clarify - are you using ***both*** databases? If not, please edit the tags and only keep those that apply to you specifically.

Comment: @sai vikas I removed inconsistent tags , please only add the dbms that is relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it means you don't want include salary of the person who is manger under his/her upper manager then :

```
select manager_id , sum(salary)
from employees
where emp_id not in (select manager_id from employee)
group by manager_id
```

if you must use `join`:

```
select manager_id , sum(salary)
from employees emp
left join employees mgr
 on mgr.emp_id = emp.managerid
where mgr.emp_id is not null
group by manager_id
```

Comment: can we write the same query using "JOIN"

Comment: why? this is most efficient way to do this query

Comment: Thanks but #eshirvana But i was curious to use joins in this context

Comment: I added another way with join fyi , please accept .upvote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: @mathguy - In the answer clearly I explained what problem this query is solving  , if this is not he want he has to explain

Comment: well , that;'s what I interpreted that he doesn't want to include salary of employees at all if he/she is a manager in any level , so  in that case this query works

Comment: @saivikas there is no difference between `left join` and `left outer join` , the first one is the short version of the second one

Comment: Hello @mathguy  in my question the query should result in showing sum of salary of employees group by manager id where the employee id should be in manager id column. To be more clear he should be manager to any one, he/she should purely be an employee and not an manager to any one in the table.

Comment: @eshirvana, i do accept your answers both the shorter one and the next one and definitely thank you for the answer.